# When proving that some statements are equivalent, should one use a circular chain of implications?

Tags: proof-writing, propositional-calculus

If I have multiple statements and have to prove that they are all equivalent, which proof strategy should I use?

E.g. let's say I have statements A, B, C and D and need to show that they are all equivalent.

I know that I can prove equivalence by proving: $A\implies B\implies C\implies D\implies A$.

My question is do I have to use a circular pattern or can I e.g., if $A\implies C$ is easier to prove than $B\implies C$, simply prove $A\implies B$, $A\implies C$, $C\implies D$, $D\implies A$ or any other random pattern?

Comment: That would give you the equivalence of $A, C$ and $D$, and $A\to B$. You would still have to show that $B\to A,C,$ or $D$. My advice is to first write down all implications that follow trivially, and then look which directions are still missing in order to have equivalence of all statements. It is always temting to use a circular pattern like $A\to B\to C\to A$, but if it turns out too difficult to prove $C\to A$ directly, then you may consider splitting it into $C\to B$ and $B\to A$.

Comment: $$A{\implies} B,B{\implies} C,C{\implies} D,D{\implies} A$$ and $$A{\implies} B,A{\implies} C,C{\implies} D,D{\implies} A$$ aren't logically equivalent: explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4251447/21813), complete with counterexamples and a truth-table proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose a,b,c,d are vertices in a directed graph.

and $(x,y)$ is an edge if you have proven $a\rightarrow b$.

Then you have proven equivalence if and only if there is a directed path from x to y for every $x,y\in {a,b,c,d}$

This is a representation of your digraph

[image]

However how can you get from point $b$ to another point?

---

Apparently this already has a name, see [implication graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implication_graph)

A digraph that satisfies the desired condition is called a [strongly connected digraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component)

Comment: You could get from B to any other point by going through A. Thanks for the illustration.

Comment: no, no, B is no connected to A, you didn't prove $b\rightarrow a$ sorry, let me make a new drwaing.

Comment: Ok I thought the arrow from D to A would run through B. I think I get your point, though.

Comment: Beautiful. Now, I have an idea as to why proof theory involves graph theory.

Answer (score 4):

It would not be enough to show that $A\to B$, $A\to C$, $C\to D$, and $D\to A$: that would show that $A,C$, and $D$ are equivalent and that any one of them implies $B$, but it would not show that $B$ was equivalent to the other three: it might be a strictly weaker statement.

Proving any collection of implications that gives you a ‘path’ from any statement in the set to any other statement in the set is sufficient. For example, you could prove $A\leftrightarrow B$, $A\leftrightarrow C$, and $A\leftrightarrow D$.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use exactly the pattern $A\Rightarrow B \Rightarrow C \Rightarrow D \Rightarrow A$, but you do need to check that you can follow arrows from any of the statements to any other.  In the example you gave, you can't get $B\Rightarrow A$ or $B\Rightarrow C$ (for instance), but if you also proved $B\Rightarrow A$ then you would be done.

Answer (score 0):

Any pattern that satisfies the condition that **you can follow the implication arrow to go from any proposition to any other proposition** works.