# Validity of a Simple Abstract Proof Method

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was just trying to abstractly capture a proof technique, and here is my little doubt as follows.

Suppose we want to prove $A \implies B$

We already have $A \implies A_{f}$

Now, of course we are to prove B yet, but still on a rough work level, given $A$, suppose $B$ holds, then we are able to deduce that

$A \land B \implies C$

Now consider that we can indeed prove that $C$ holds, independently of $B$, i.e. by $A \implies C$,

Then,

$((A \implies A_{f}) \land (A \implies C)) \implies (A \implies (A_{f} \land C))\;$

(Indeed both sides are logically equivalent as truth tables are same.)

Now we have that $A \implies (A_{f} \land C)$. In the setting, it is also provable that $(A_{f} \land C) \implies B$. This suffices to prove that $A \implies B$, But my main question is that *"does the derivation of $C$ from $A \land B \implies C$ have any effect on the validity of the proof?"*

$C$ was obtained as a rough work from assuming $B$, along with the given $A$, and that was it. I know that one shouldn't assume what one's trying to prove, but for the case of $C$ here, its truth was supplied by $A$ and not $B$, as it was provable by $A \implies C$

$C$, for the matter of proof, was deducible from $A$ alone, and the two truths deduced from $A$ alone suffice to prove $A \implies B$.

The rough work of $A \land B \implies C$ just served as a guess for looking out for such $C$ which could aid in proof.

It might've not been much of a question, but I just wanted to confirm a doubt which I hadn't encountered before.

Comment: Well, you have to prove that $A \implies C$ regardless of $B$.  So you didn't just prove $A\land B \implies C$ you *also* proved $A \land -\lnot A \implies C$ and $A \land Q\implies C$ and $A\land \text{PURPLEMONKEYDISHWASHER} \implies C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is different from, but so similar in motivation to, [this Question that I Answered yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4495116/21813), that it feels pertinent to point to it first.

To summarise: you are able to independently prove the following (I'm rewriting $A_f$ simply as $F):$

1. $A→F,$
2. $(A∧B)→C,$
3. $A→C,$
4. $(F∧C)→B.$

Now, the truth table below shows that **hypotheses 1,3 and 4** jointly imply that $(A→B),$ that is, that $$\Big(   (A→F)   ∧   (A→C) ∧  ((F∧C)→B)   \Big)\implies(A→B).$$ (Hypothesis 2 is [an unnecessary condition](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/25404/372).) Thus, the above four hypotheses also ***do*** jointly imply that $$A→B.$$

\begin{array}{cccc|c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}c@{}ccc@{}c@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}c@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}c@{}c}
a&b&c&f&(&(&(&(&a&\rightarrow&f&)&\land&(&a&\rightarrow&c&)&)&\land&(&(&f&\land&c&)&\rightarrow&b&)&)&\rightarrow&(&a&\rightarrow&b&)&)\\\hline
1&1&1&1&&&&&1&1&1&&1&&1&1&1&&&1&&&1&1&1&&1&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&1&1&1&&\\
1&1&1&0&&&&&1&0&0&&0&&1&1&1&&&0&&&0&0&1&&1&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&1&1&1&&\\
1&1&0&1&&&&&1&1&1&&0&&1&0&0&&&0&&&1&0&0&&1&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&1&1&1&&\\
1&1&0&0&&&&&1&0&0&&0&&1&0&0&&&0&&&0&0&0&&1&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&1&1&1&&\\
1&0&1&1&&&&&1&1&1&&1&&1&1&1&&&0&&&1&1&1&&0&0&&&\mathbf{1}&&1&0&0&&\\
1&0&1&0&&&&&1&0&0&&0&&1&1&1&&&0&&&0&0&1&&1&0&&&\mathbf{1}&&1&0&0&&\\
1&0&0&1&&&&&1&1&1&&0&&1&0&0&&&0&&&1&0&0&&1&0&&&\mathbf{1}&&1&0&0&&\\
1&0&0&0&&&&&1&0&0&&0&&1&0&0&&&0&&&0&0&0&&1&0&&&\mathbf{1}&&1&0&0&&\\
0&1&1&1&&&&&0&1&1&&1&&0&1&1&&&1&&&1&1&1&&1&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&1&&\\
0&1&1&0&&&&&0&1&0&&1&&0&1&1&&&1&&&0&0&1&&1&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&1&&\\
0&1&0&1&&&&&0&1&1&&1&&0&1&0&&&1&&&1&0&0&&1&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&1&&\\
0&1&0&0&&&&&0&1&0&&1&&0&1&0&&&1&&&0&0&0&&1&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&1&&\\
0&0&1&1&&&&&0&1&1&&1&&0&1&1&&&0&&&1&1&1&&0&0&&&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&0&&\\
0&0&1&0&&&&&0&1&0&&1&&0&1&1&&&1&&&0&0&1&&1&0&&&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&0&&\\
0&0&0&1&&&&&0&1&1&&1&&0&1&0&&&1&&&1&0&0&&1&0&&&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&0&&\\
0&0&0&0&&&&&0&1&0&&1&&0&1&0&&&1&&&0&0&0&&1&0&&&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&0&&
\end{array}

Answer (score 2):

You're right. It doesn't matter that your goal $B$ inspired you to think of the proposition $C$, as long as the deduction you ultimately produce doesn't assume $B$ is true in order to prove $B$.

It's very common to "think backwards" and leave logical gaps in one's mental model of a solution while building intuition for a problem, and then to "erase" most of that reasoning to obtain a clean formal proof. What matters in the end is the validity (and clarity) of the resulting argument.