# Proof of $(x\subseteq y)\leftrightarrow(x\cap y =x)\leftrightarrow(x\cup y=y)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

Exercise 1.2.1(vii) from Page 5 of Keith Devlin's "The Joy of Sets":

> Prove the following assertion directly from the definitions. The
> drawing of "Venn diagrams" is forbidden; this is an exercise in the
> manipulation of logical formalisms.
> $$(x\subseteq y)\leftrightarrow(x\cap y =x)\leftrightarrow(x\cup y=y)$$

**Attempt at solution**:

This is not a difficult claim to understand or prove in terms of sets, but I can't figure out the pure logical formalism. I guess I should break this into seven individual implications?

1. $\forall w(w\in x\rightarrow w\in y)\rightarrow \forall z(z\in x\rightarrow (z\in x\enspace\wedge\enspace z\in y)) $
2. $\forall w(w\in x\rightarrow w\in y)\rightarrow \forall z((z\in x\enspace\wedge\enspace z\in y)\rightarrow z\in x))$
3. $\forall z(z\in x\rightarrow(z\in x \enspace\wedge\enspace z\in y))\rightarrow \forall w(w\in x\rightarrow w\in y)$
4. $\forall z(z\in x\rightarrow(z\in x \enspace\wedge\enspace z\in y))\rightarrow \forall w((w
   \in x \enspace\lor\enspace w\in y)\rightarrow w\in y)$
5. $\forall z(z\in x\rightarrow(z\in x \enspace\wedge\enspace z\in y))\rightarrow \forall w(w\in y\rightarrow(w
   \in x \enspace\lor\enspace w\in y))$
6. $\forall w((w\in x\enspace\lor\enspace w\in y)\rightarrow w\in y)\rightarrow\forall z((z\in x \enspace\wedge\enspace z\in y)\rightarrow z\in x)$
7. $\forall w((w\in x\enspace\lor\enspace w\in y)\rightarrow w\in y)\rightarrow\forall z(z\in x \rightarrow (z\in x \enspace\wedge\enspace z\in y))$

In addition to wondering if I'm doing this correctly, I also feel like I gained nothing from writing out these implications.

Comment: Is the exercise requiring you to prove that the three sentences (each enclosed in parentheses) are equivalent to one another? *Strictly logically* speaking (see the final paragraph of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4495116/21813)), that's not what that sentence (with the two "if and only if"s) is saying, even though that's what it would typically mean in mathematics. I'm asking for this clarification because this exercise is after all demanding "logical formalism".

Comment: @ryang The instructions I included in the original post are all that Devlin gives the reader.

Comment: @ryang Hmm...browsing some other posts, its seems that logic people like you make a distinction between $\iff$ and $\leftrightarrow$? I am editing the OP now because Devlin used $\leftrightarrow$ and I didn't realize there was a difference.

Comment: @ryang I understand from your linked posts that, under the "all three statements are equivalent" interpretation, it is not necessary to prove all seven implications. For example, proving $A\rightarrow B$, $B\rightarrow C$ and $C\rightarrow A$ would be sufficient. Beyond writing out those implications, I don't know how to proceed. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You are missing a lot of quantifiers. Also, the parentheses you just added to number 2 seem like not what you intended.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you! I think I corrected the mistakes. I still don't know what would suffice as a "proof" though.

Comment: @ryang Sure. I have no opinion on the matter except that I should defer to the opinion of a person with more expertise than I (i.e., you).

Comment: @ryang I understand. This exercise appears only on page five. Other than the instructions from the OP, the only material on the first five pages that I could see as having any bearing on the interpretation question is on page two, where Devlin writes that $\rightarrow$ abbreviates 'implies'  and $\leftrightarrow$ abbreviates 'if and only if'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Exercise 1.2.1(vii) from **page 5** of Keith Devlin's "The Joy of Sets":
>
> > Prove the following assertion **directly from the definitions**.  this is an exercise in the **manipulation of logical formalisms**.
> > $$x\subseteq y\;\leftrightarrow\;x\cap y =x\;\leftrightarrow\;x\cup y=y.\tag{*}$$

Even though this exercise is requesting "logical formalism" and sentence $(*)$ does not [technically](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4495116/21813) mean that those three  atomic statements are equivalent to one another, the author quite certainly is wanting you to prove just that.

> I understand from your linked post that it is not necessary to prove all seven implications; proving $(A→B),\; (B→C)$ and $(C→A)$ would be sufficient.

Yes. So, we just need

1. $∀p\;(p\in X→p\in Y)→∀q\;(q\in X\cap Y ↔ q\in X)$
2. $∀q\;(q\in X\cap Y ↔ q\in X)→∀r\;(r\in X\cup Y ↔ r\in Y)$
3. $∀r\;(r\in X\cup Y ↔ r\in Y)→∀p\;(p\in X→p\in Y)$

or, alternatively,

1. $∀p\;(p\in X→p\in Y)→∀q\;(q\in X\cap Y ↔ q\in X)$
2. $∀p\;(p\in X→p\in Y)→∀r\;(r\in X\cup Y ↔ r\in Y)$
3. $∀q\;(q\in X\cap Y ↔ q\in X)→∀p\;(p\in X→p\in Y)$
4. $∀r\;(r\in X\cup Y ↔ r\in Y)→∀p\;(p\in X→p\in Y)$

(the definition of subset has been applied).

---

**Addendum 1**

> I believe my #1 and #2 from the OP are equivalent to your #1.  If you look at **my #1** for example, I really don't know what more I can do to "prove" this.

Okay, let's reformat **your #1**, using $Ab$ to denote $b\in A:$
$$∀p\:(Xp → Yp) → ∀q\:(Xq → (Xq ∧ Yq)).\tag 4$$ This is logically equivalent to $$∀q\:∃p\:\Big((Xp → Yp) → (Xq → (Xq ∧ Yq))\Big),\tag 3$$ which is logically equivalent to $$∀q\:∃p\:\Big((Xp → Yp) → (Xq → Yq)\Big),\tag 2$$ which is a logical consequence (choose $p:=q$) of $$∀q\:\Big((Xq → Yq) → (Xq → Yq)\Big),\tag 1$$ which is clearly true. Notice that this proof is purely logical, utilising no result from Set Theory.

On the other hand, after the relevant results have been introduced after page 5, then a proof of the first part of $(*),$ $$X\subseteq Y\implies X\cap Y =X,$$ can simply (with the relevant justifications) be: $$X⊆Y \implies X∩Y⊆X\\
\text{and }X⊆Y \implies X⊆X∩Y.$$

---

**Addendum 2**

> Thanks. I don't understand why $(4)$ and $(3)$ are logically equivalent.

Paring them down (here, $Mn$ denotes that object $n$ holds property $M):$
\begin{gather}∀p\:Fp → ∀q\:Gq\tag 4
\\∀q\:∃p\:\big(Fp → Gq\big)\tag 3\end{gather}

Sentence $(3)$ is the [Prenex form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication) of sentence $(4).$ They are logically equivalent because (here, $\psi$ is a sentence) \begin{gather}\psi → ∀q\:Gq\quad\equiv\quad ∀q\;(\psi → Gq),\tag{L1}\\
∀p\:Fp → \psi \quad\equiv\quad ∃q\;(Fp → \psi).\tag{L2}
\end{gather}

$(\mathrm L1)$ and $(\mathrm L2)$ contains four logical entailments; their formal proofs can be found in exercises 3 & 6 on p. 114 & 116 of [this book](https://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc-solutions.pdf). I'll illustrate the least obvious one $$∀p\:Fp → \psi \quad\models\quad ∃q\;(Fp → \psi)$$ with an example:

- premise: “Dark matter exists if every perfumier is French.”
- conclusion: “For some perfumier, dark matter exists if they're French.”

If every perfumier is French, then the conclusion clearly follows from the premise. On the other hand, if some perfumier isn't French, then for *that* perfumier, “dark matter exists if they're French” is indeed (vacuously) true, and the conclusion is again true.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing these proofs using Proof Designer:

https://djvelleman.people.amherst.edu/pd.html

I think the result would be the kind of proof that Devlin has in mind.

Comment: To test the tool, I tried entering $X\subseteq Y$ as a hypothesis and $X\cap Y=X$ as the conclusion. The resulting "proof" was nothing but "Proof of $X\cap Y=X$ goes here."

Comment: Right.  Now you have to construct the proof.  The software will help you do that, but it won't write the proof for you.  In the File menu, choose Help to get instructions.